# new String(byte[]). Will this allocate memory in both heap and String pool

Tags: java, string, performance, memory

```
String someString = new String(byte[]);
```

Will the above code allocate memory for the string char array in String pool?

I wanted to know whether any difference in the memory footprint made by the following code samples.

```
//Sample 1
String someString = new String(byte[]);

//Sample 2
String someString = new String("someStringLiteral");
```

Comment: Strings created via `new String(whatever)` will not be automatically moved to String Pool. But if you will use as `whatever` some string literal then *that literal* will be either taken from String Pool, or will be put into pool if there was none before (now where is that duplicate question...).

Comment: @Pshemo There's no question of 'if there was none before'. It *is* in the string pool. It's a literal. It was put there by the compiler and classloader.

Comment: @EJP Can you explain what you mean by "*It was put there by the compiler and classloader*"? From what I remember literals end in pool when they are used first time, not necessary when class is loaded. Lets take this example: http://ideone.com/5Qwfun. If I understand correctly `literal` contains same string as `str` which suggests that `str.intern()` happened before placing `"foo"` in pool (so before loading this class).

Comment: @EJP Just to be clear I am still learning about Java so I believe that my understanding may not be correct and will be very grateful for any informations or corrections you can provide.